# How do I alphabetize JSON element > 1 level down with localeCompare()?

Tags: javascript, string, string-comparison

I just created an alphabetize function for a Javascript-based app I'm working on, using a combo of `sort()` and `localeCompare()`. Each part of the JSON has an attribute 'name' that the code below uses:

```
  var alphabetize = function() {
    flatresponse.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    });
    console.log(flatresponse); 
    });
  };
  alphabetize(); //A-Z sorted!
```

Example flatresponse object:

```
  { workbookId: '148',
    updatedAt: '2016-02-10T12:45:24.707Z',
    usageInfo: 
     { hitsTotal: 2,
       hitsLastOneMonthTotal: 0,
       hitsLastThreeMonthsTotal: 0,
       hitsLastTwelveMonthsTotal: 0,
       favoritesTotal: 0 },
    thumbnailUrl: 'vizportal/api/rest/v1/views/753/thumbnail?1455108324707',
    name: 'Sales Forecast',
    id: '753',
    path: 'Sales/SalesForecast',
    index: '2',
    serverUrl: 'tableau.biztory.be',
    workbookName: 'Sales',
    siteName: '23Seconds' },
  { workbookId: '182',
    updatedAt: '2016-03-16T09:05:07.176Z',
    usageInfo: 
     { hitsTotal: 0,
       hitsLastOneMonthTotal: 0,
       hitsLastThreeMonthsTotal: 0,
       hitsLastTwelveMonthsTotal: 0,
       favoritesTotal: 0 },
    thumbnailUrl: 'vizportal/api/rest/v1/views/890/thumbnail?1458119107176',
    name: 'Sales Forecast',
    id: '890',
    path: 'WebServicesLayer/SalesForecast',
    index: '2',
    serverUrl: 'tableau.biztory.be',
    workbookName: 'Web Services Layer',
    siteName: '23Seconds' },
  { workbookId: '175',
    updatedAt: '2016-03-01T14:22:32.360Z',
    usageInfo: 
     { hitsTotal: 2,
       hitsLastOneMonthTotal: 0,
       hitsLastThreeMonthsTotal: 1,
       hitsLastTwelveMonthsTotal: 1,
       favoritesTotal: 0 },
    thumbnailUrl: 'vizportal/api/rest/v1/views/860/thumbnail?1456842152360',
    name: 'Sales per category',
    id: '860',
    path: 'ExampleBaxter/Salespercategory',
    index: '1',
    serverUrl: 'tableau.biztory.be',
    workbookName: 'Example Baxter',
    siteName: '23Seconds' }
```

I'm wondering how to adapt this for elements that are further down the tree, e.g. sort on `a.usageInfo.hitsTotal`? Or any element x levels down for that matter?

Comment: but if `name` is a string, then you can not have `name.nickname`.

Comment: I meant just any string element that's more than 1 level down. `city.street` if you like, whatever. `return a.city.street.localeCompare(b.city.street);` doesn't work obviously, so what would be the easiest way then?

Comment: please add the data structure, you have.

Comment: Updated with an example flatresponse json object.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you could sort your data by

- `usageInfo.hitsTotal` and
- `usageInfo.hitsLastTwelveMonthsTotal`

both descending.

```js
var data = [{ workbookId: '148', updatedAt: '2016-02-10T12:45:24.707Z', usageInfo: { hitsTotal: 2, hitsLastOneMonthTotal: 0, hitsLastThreeMonthsTotal: 0, hitsLastTwelveMonthsTotal: 0, favoritesTotal: 0 }, thumbnailUrl: 'vizportal/api/rest/v1/views/753/thumbnail?1455108324707', name: 'Sales Forecast', id: '753', path: 'Sales/SalesForecast', index: '2', serverUrl: 'tableau.biztory.be', workbookName: 'Sales', siteName: '23Seconds' }, { workbookId: '182', updatedAt: '2016-03-16T09:05:07.176Z', usageInfo: { hitsTotal: 0, hitsLastOneMonthTotal: 0, hitsLastThreeMonthsTotal: 0, hitsLastTwelveMonthsTotal: 0, favoritesTotal: 0 }, thumbnailUrl: 'vizportal/api/rest/v1/views/890/thumbnail?1458119107176', name: 'Sales Forecast', id: '890', path: 'WebServicesLayer/SalesForecast', index: '2', serverUrl: 'tableau.biztory.be', workbookName: 'Web Services Layer', siteName: '23Seconds' }, { workbookId: '175', updatedAt: '2016-03-01T14:22:32.360Z', usageInfo: { hitsTotal: 2, hitsLastOneMonthTotal: 0, hitsLastThreeMonthsTotal: 1, hitsLastTwelveMonthsTotal: 1, favoritesTotal: 0 }, thumbnailUrl: 'vizportal/api/rest/v1/views/860/thumbnail?1456842152360', name: 'Sales per category', id: '860', path: 'ExampleBaxter/Salespercategory', index: '1', serverUrl: 'tableau.biztory.be', workbookName: 'Example Baxter', siteName: '23Seconds' }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.usageInfo.hitsTotal - a.usageInfo.hitsTotal || b.usageInfo.hitsLastTwelveMonthsTotal - a.usageInfo.hitsLastTwelveMonthsTotal;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```